# Visual Studio design time event handling

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, design-time

I am trying to create a WPF wizard control in visual studio. I am successful except I would like to navigate the pages in design time by clicking the next and previous buttons. The pages are being written in xaml. I can navigate the pages by going to the properties window and changing the selected index, but I would like something more user-friendly. I remember doing something similar in a winforms project having something to do with overriding maybe wndproc and listening to mouse click events from the designer.

So I've been googling and I can't seem to google the right words to bring this up.

Can anyone please help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom Adorner as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514670%28VS.100%29.aspx).  There are two walkthroughs there that should help.

Ultimately, you would need to overlay a transparent button on top of your actual buttons. Then in the click handlers you'd update your selected item/index.